# @users.includes by has_one association's has_many assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models which are interplaying --

```
Users has_one CommonApp

CommonApp has_many Cities
```

I have a small form on a user index page, and would like to filter `@users` by whether or not that user's associated common_app is associated to a city with `params[:city_id]`.

Right now I have

```
@city = City.find(params[:city_id]) if params[:city_id] && params[:city_id] != "0"
@users = @users.includes(:cities).where(cities: { id: @city }) if @city
```

I know this is wrong though, because @users is not associated to :cities.

How would I change the above so that it's regarding the @user's common_app's association to cities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to allow direct access to cities through a user in your User model:

```
has_many :cities, through: :common_app
```

Then you can use filtering code as you have written it.